# CSS nth-of-type refuses to obey

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Unfortunately, for me, the nth-of-type selector is refusing to obey the orders in a simple scenario [shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/HJm49/)

This is the HTML used to test:

```
<div class="help-title">
    TITLE
</div>
<div class="help-warn-left">
    ERROR
</div>
<div class="help-warn-right">
    ERROR MESS
</div>

<div class="help-section">
    <div class="help-header">
        TEXT1
    </div>
    <div class="help-body">
        TEXT2
    </div>
</div>


<div class="help-section">
    <div class="help-header">
        TEXT3
    </div>
    <div class="help-body">
        TEXT4
    </div>
</div>


<div class="help-section">
    <div class="help-header">
        TEXT5
    </div>
    <div class="help-body">
        TEXT6
    </div>
</div>


<div class="help-section">
    <div class="help-header">
        TEXT7
    </div>
    <div class="help-body">
        TEXT8
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
div.help-section{
    color:blue;
    /*background:yellow;*/
}

div.help-section:nth-of-type(2)
{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

When I remove comment around the yellow background, the help-section will have a yellow background, so it clearly agrees to having a background set. However, the order given below, which demands that the 2nd help-section have a red background but it is simply refusing to obey me! Is it my browser? Firefox v24.0? Or is it I that doesn't know what nth-of-type does?

What I expect it to do is to select the 2nd div with the class help-section found within the body. Obviously, I am missing something here.

Comment: It is not your browser.

Comment: Please define what you want to have happen.

Comment: @sheriffderek Ok thanks for checking that out.

Comment: @sheriffderek Updated question with that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use a different element just for these sections

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/JXN92/)

### HTML

```
<section class="help-section">
    <div class="help-header">
        TEXT1
    </div>
    <div class="help-body">
        TEXT2
    </div>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
section:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted this, its a valid work-around unless there are sections elsewhere in the page. So I accept this answer to spite the downer.

Comment: Things to be learned from both. Weird though. I guess I don't fully understand why it's not seeing them as a group. I almost always put things in lists and li's always get picked up.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is that you have to specify the parent from which you want to count the child that match your selector. So you would have to change your css to be similar to:

```
div.container div.help-section:nth-of-type(3)
{
    color:red;
}
```

and add

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

around your helper section. I tried this using body selector but with no luck.

More info here : http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/HJm49/1/

Comment: sorry I changed it from the 2nd nth-of-type to the 3rd.

Comment: Yeah... that's what I found as well... It seems like it needs a more specific scope  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/JXN92/  It works if you remove the preceding divs from the OP's sections.

Comment: you beat me to it.. +1

Comment: The issue with that is still that the help-section class is pointless as it gets ignored.

Comment: btw, @ShalomAptekar, i know it's probably too chatty for here, but... nice website, man!

Comment: heheh thank you :) I'm working on making it easier to read! Check out how the effect is done, it doesn't use any CSS ;)